# Changing background color of subview not working

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, storyboard, drawrect

I have a very simple UIViewController whose main view has the following structure:

```
UIView
-->CustomView
```

My CustomView looks like this

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Init with frame %f,%f,%f,%f", self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height]);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Drawing CGRect %f,%f,%f,%f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height]);
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
}
```

In the log, I can see that the `init` is called with the proper frame, but my `drawRect` method is never called, and the **first** `backgroundColor` (the blue one) change doesn't even work.

If I set my top view (UIView in the figure above) to `CustomView`, then the background does change to blue and the `drawRect` gets called; the background doesn't change to yellow though.

I don't really understand what's going on and I'd like to get your input thanks.

Comment: revealapp.com is really useful for debugging view hierarchy issues like this.

Comment: Thanks that app is really cool! I used and it says my custom view has a frame of size (0,0) even though in my init log it has the correct frame CGRect {{71, 152}, {179, 61}}. It's really weird because I have a label in my view which shows, but in Reveal it shows the label is outside of my view, below it...

Comment: actually it's just the height of my view that gets set to 0 between the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear of my ViewController

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the custom view is not being showed. Has it been properly added as a subview to the top view? Have you checked if its superview is the top view (UIView)?

Comment: Yes its superview is the UIView and it's shown because I have a label in it and I can see it, thanks though